# ASR9K XML API - Can't Authenticate

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios-xr, cisco-asr

Trying to set up the XML API on an ASR 9K and find myself unable to authenticate with the XML API using Netcat.

I've configured the box as below:

```
Building configuration...
!! IOS XR Configuration 5.1.2
!! Last configuration change at Wed Apr 15 07:19:42 2015 by root
!
username xml
group sysadmin
secret 5 $1$LY8B$39t3eTXf/ajMGWnX99.ux0
password 7 07182E414C080D1657
!
aaa authorization exec default group tacacs+ local
interface MgmtEth0/RSP0/CPU0/0
ipv4 address 10.2.100.1 255.255.0.0
!
interface MgmtEth0/RSP0/CPU0/1
 shutdown
!
interface TenGigE0/0/2/0
 shutdown
!
interface TenGigE0/0/2/1
 shutdown
!
interface TenGigE0/0/2/2
 shutdown
!
interface TenGigE0/0/2/3
 shutdown
!
router static
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  0.0.0.0/0 10.2.0.1
 !
!
ssh server v2
xml agent ssl
!
xml agent tty
!
xml agent
iteration on size 100
!
end
```

and 
    RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:ios# xml echo
    Wed Apr 15 07:27:10.765 UTC
    XML>

I've got two test users, root:root and xml, both of which I can connect to using SSH though the XML interface seems to reject them - using nc:

```
alexanderturner@Alexanders-MacBook-Pro~/Downloads> nc -v 10.2.100.1 38751
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
    1:  flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
    outif en0
    src 10.0.1.40 port 61066
    dst 10.2.100.1 port 38751
    rank info not available
    TCP aux info available

Connection to 10.2.100.1 port 38751 [tcp/*] succeeded!


User Access Verification

Username: root
Password: root


User Access Verification
```

Is this not authing against local?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue with nc, works fine with telnet :/